# Button as subview of ImageView is unable to be tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

ViewController->View->ScrollView->ImageView->Buttons

I've got buttons that I am adding as subviews of my imageView, and I can't tap any of them.  I have tried adding the action with the event `.touchUpInside` and `.touchDown`.  I also have a breakpoint inside the `touchesBegan` function, and it never gets activated.  I have printed the bounds of the imageView as well as the bounds of some of the buttons, and to my knowledge of how bounds work, they should be inside the bounds of the imageView. Why Are my Buttons actions not being triggered when I Tap Them?

```
class myVC: UIViewController {

    var data: Data

    // MARK: UIComponents
    lazy var scrollView: PassThroughScrollView = { //These PassThrough Views just return false on a hitTest, Code for them is below
        let _scrollView = PassThroughScrollView(frame: .zero)
        _scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        _scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        _scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return _scrollView
    }()

    lazy var imageView: PassThroughImageView = {
        let _imageView = PassThroughImageView(frame: .zero)
        _imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        _imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        _imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return _imageView
    }()

    init(dat: data) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.data = dat
        self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: UIImage(named: "img"), completed: nil)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    // MARK: Setup

    private func setup() {
        let viewController = self
        let interactor = PlaySectionInteractor()
        let presenter = PlaySectionPresenter()
        let router = PlaySectionRouter()
        viewController.interactor = interactor
        viewController.router = router
        interactor.presenter = presenter
        presenter.viewController = viewController
        router.viewController = viewController
        router.dataStore = interactor
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        setupHotSpots()

    }

    private func setupViews() {
    }

    private func setupButtons() {
        for s in data!.ButtonPoints! {
            let button = customButton(point: point)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            imageView.addSubview(button)

            let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sizeConstants.hotspotSize),
                button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sizeConstants.hotspotSize),
                button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(s.x!) * 1920 / 100),
                button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor, constant: CGFloat(s.y!) * 1080 / 100),
            ])
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) //I Have tried both .touchUpInside and .touchDown
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        setupConstraints()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        var touch: UITouch? = touches.first

        if touch?.view != detailView {
            detailView.isHidden = true
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    @objc func tapButton(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button Successfully Tapped)
    }
}
```

Pass Through Views:

```
class PassThroughView: UIView {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            let convertedPoint = convert(point, to: subview)
            let point = subview.point(inside: convertedPoint, with: event)
            if (point) {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}

class PassThroughImageView: UIImageView {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            let convertedPoint = convert(point, to: subview)
            let point = subview.point(inside: convertedPoint, with: event)
            if (point) {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}

class PassThroughScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            let convertedPoint = convert(point, to: subview)
            let point = subview.point(inside: convertedPoint, with: event)
            if (point) {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `PassThrough...View`s? You add the action `tapHotspot` but in the code there is only method `tapButton`. Where is `tapHotspot`?

Comment: I need the passthrough Views because from my understanding, the input would be intercepted by the views on top of the buttons in the view hierarchy.  Also, I renamed that function for stackOverflow to be more clear, I forgot to change it in both places.  It's fixed now @dasdom

Comment: Have you tried if it works if you don't use the pass through versions?

Comment: @dasdom I did when I started having this issue, but that was one of my first attempts at fixing it, so i've changed a few things since then.

Comment: @GabeSpound - you seem to have a ***lot*** going on there, and it's impossible to tell what's needed and what's not. In the code you posted, `PlaySectionInteractor`, `PlaySectionPresenter`, `PlaySectionRouter`, `setupHotSpots`, `detailView` are all *unresolved identifiers*, along with other missing information. I ***strongly*** suggest starting simple: add a button as a subview of an imageView, give the button a `touchUpInside` target, and see if that works. Then add the imageVIew to a scrollView. Works? Take the next step, and so on.